# ManyToMany between User, Group and a Role table causes __construct() must be of the type array, object given error

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.8

I am working in a Symfony 2.8 project using FOSUserBundle (dev-master) and I am trying to extend a few things like for example the roles. Why? Because I need a menu system based on permissions and roles and this is the only way I found to achieve this. (if any knows a better one pls let me know I am open to ideas and suggestions). Right now I am trying to setup a `ManytoMany` between `User<->Role` and `ManyToMany` between `Group<->Role`. `Role` is a entity I have created for this purpose. Below is the code for the `Role` entity (I have strip out a few comments for not make the post to long):

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_role")
 */
class Role
{
    use IdentifierAutogeneratedTrait;
    use Timestampable;
    use ActiveTrait;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=150)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * @var User[]
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="roleUsers", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $users;

    /**
     * @var Group[]
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group", mappedBy="roleGroups", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    protected $groups;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->groups = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    ... // getter and setter for common properties

    /**
     * @return User[]|ArrayCollection
     */
    public function getUsers()
    {
        return $this->users;
    }

    /**
     * @param User[] $users
     */
    public function setUsers($users)
    {
        $this->users->clear();
        $this->users = new ArrayCollection($users);
    }

    /**
     * @param $user User The user to associate
     */
    public function addUser($user)
    {
        if (!$this->users->contains($user)) {
            $this->users[] = $user;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param User $user
     */
    public function removeUser($user)
    {
        $this->users->removeElement($user);
    }

    /**
     * @param Group[] $groups
     */
    public function setGroups($groups)
    {
        $this->groups->clear();
        $this->groups = new ArrayCollection($groups);
    }

    /**
     * @param $group Group The group to associate
     */
    public function addGroup($group)
    {
        if (!$this->groups->contains($group)) {
            $this->groups[] = $group;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param Group $group
     */
    public function removeGroup($group)
    {
        $this->groups->removeElement($group);
    }
}
```

And this is the code for the `User` entity (again strip some comments for the same reason):

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="fos_user_has_group",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    protected $groups;

    /**
     * @var Role[]
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="users", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="fos_user_has_role")
     */
    protected $roleUsers;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->roleUsers = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @param $role Role the role to associate
     */
    public function addRol($role)
    {
        $role->addUser($this);

        if (!$this->roleUsers->contains($role)) {
            $this->roleUsers->add($role);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $role Role the role to remove
     */
    public function removeRol($role)
    {
        $role->removeCommand($this);
        $this->roleUsers->removeElement($role);
    }

    /**
     * @return Role[]
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->roleUsers;
    }

    /**
     * @param Role[] $role
     */
    public function setRole($role)
    {
        // This is the owning side, we have to call remove and add to have change in the alias side too.
        foreach ($this->getRoles() as $roles) {
            $this->removeRol($roles);
        }
        foreach ($roles as $role) {
            $this->addRol($role);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param $id
     */
    public function removeAssociationById($id)
    {
        foreach ($this->roleUsers as $role) {
            if ($role->getId() == $id) {
                $this->roleUsers->removeElement($role);

                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Before this changes all was working good and for all I mean I can create a new user, promote to any ROLE and login into the system. After the changes the first error I have when login is this one:

> Type error: Argument 4 passed to Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken::__construct() must be of the type array, object given, called in 
>   /var/www/html/platform-cm/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Provider/UserAuthenticationProvider.php on line 96

I am not sure what could be wrong, can any give me some help to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To archive several roles you dont need to create another table, the entity provided by FOSUserBundle that implements the Symfony AdvancedUserInterface has a role field that maps as array and you can set several roles on it.

I understand that you may want to CRUD those roles and for that you want to add that other entity. But there are so many little cases where you can CRUD a ROLE without changing any piece of code, example:

You have some menu that shows if the user has the role PLAYER but a then you create through this new entity the role MULTI_PLAYER, but you will need to code the MULTI_PLAYER menu, controllers, business logic to be short. So my advice its not to complicate to much ROLES since it will always be bind to a code feature.

But if still that its what you want to archive, FOSUserBundle comes with a group functionality that i think you should review, in your current entities you are creating this new Role entity but the bundles provides the Group entity with also a field roles to store many roles on it.

The answer to you question if im right its that your getRoles method its returning an object when it suppose to return an array of strings.